# How can I pre-load an html form if the form has already been submitted?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a search website.
I want the search bar form from my home page to be visible on the results page.

What solutions are there for pre-loading all the various elements of my form?
There's 3 text fields, 2 radio buttons, and two checkboxes.

Currently I'm having to interrupt each element with a php function that will see if the $_GET['valueName'] is equal to current element option, but that seems too complex and ugly to be standard.

parallel example:

```
<select name="section">
<option value="free" selected="<? if($_GET['section'] == 'free'){echo 'selected';} ?>">Free</option>
<option value="under100" selected="<? if($_GET['section'] == 'under100'){echo 'selected';} ?>">Under $100</option>
<option value="under200" selected="<? if($_GET['section'] == 'under200'){echo 'selected';} ?>">Under $200</option>
<option value="any" selected="<? if($_GET['section'] == 'any'){echo 'selected';} ?>">Any price</option>
    </select>
```

I haven't ran that to know it even works, but is there not a client-side way of populating a form?

Comment: Can you give us some code or more info on what you are trying to do.

Comment: " I want the search bar form from my home page to be visible on the results page." question: are you not implementing this as template wherein there are snippets of html code that you could just include?

Comment: My landing page has a search bar at the top of the page. I copied and pasted that code into the .php file that is called when you sumbit that form.

I want the form on the results.php page to show the values entered in the search from the index page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want variables from a form passed to another page and shown on that page you could do something like:

```
<form action="new_page.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="search_phrase">
</form>
```

Then on your new_page you can load them and display them:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['search_phrase'])){ echo $_POST['search_phrase']; }
?>
```

This is probably the most simple way to load form data onto your new page; if you don't want to use frames, divs, or AJAX. I would have gave a more specific answer but you didn't give example code; but either way this method should work just fine.

If you want the entire search bar itself included in both pages you could put the search bar in a different php file and just import it with:

```
include('my_search_bar.php');
```

And if you think the $_GET is ugly and interrupting you can use POST (it does not put variables in your link like link.php?var=abc... Also if you check if your post variables are set at the very top of your page you can make it so all those are required before the functions will execute and display variables making the functions seem more etiquette flowing.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I appreciate your patience.

Comment: And I DO want an AJAX method! I just need this to work before I spend the time reading up on ajax.

Comment: @Brian: Well the thing about AJAX is can only really be utilized when you want to load data or make calculations without the page refreshing (staying on the same page). That method could be just as easy; but if you run a search from another page that redirects you using AJAX wouldn't make sense. But for making searches from the results page could prove to be useful. So how far are you on the PHP work and what do you still need help with?

Comment: I'd have to agree. With what Brian is doing there is no need to use AJAX for what he is needing to do.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys. @Devon- My php is working and 'done,' but its never finished. But I don't have anything at all for styling or client scripting.

Comment: Do you think Google uses server side scripting to fill their post-search search bar?
http://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=search&oq=search&fp=b44db6a72e89b15f

Comment: @Brian: We are glad to help; also please remember to check off my solution as the answer so others know your question was answered. As for the Google search bar question; their scripts run on both client-side and server-side in the idea that when you update the bar with new information AJAX functions are run and make calls to the server-side back end to send you new data.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<input type="text" name="search" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['your_var']){ echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['your_var']);}?>">
```

Then for check boxes/radio you'd do a loop I believe, but I can't remember right of the top of my head.

Comment: There's not a simple javascript method for this? Or a special html attribute?

Comment: For $_GET's you can window.location.search (i'm not sure if/what jQuery's function is) but you'd have to use something like loc = split('&' window.location.search) then use a for loop for each individual values with split('=', your_var). I'm not too sure about  how to do $_POST's